# Generating MobileFirst ID Token for non-mobile client

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

Objective is to invoke MobileFirst adapter APIs from non-mobile client.

Mobile first platform version: `7.1.0.00.20180425-1124`

Article [Exposing mobile services to non-mobile (confidential) clients](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHSCD_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_non_mobile_to_mobile_services.html), helped me generate `access_token`. I am able to invoke adapter APIs. However my adapter extracts certain information from the logged in user identity, which comes out to be `null`

```
WLServerAPIProvider.getWLServerAPI().getSecurityAPI().getSecurityContext().getUserIdentity()
```

By [definition](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHSCD_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_oauth_security_tokens.html#oauth_tokens__id_tokens), `access token` is the authorization permissions of a client, not the user. It is the `ID Token` that contains information about the device, application, and user identity.

Can someone please help with generating test ID token? Is it a [unknown limitation - #User Certificate Authentication feature limitations](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHSCD_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/start/c_known_limitations.html)? Work-arounds?